# Django views database value remains '\'\

Tags: jquery, sql, ajax, django, forms

I am pretty new to web-dev and was asked to write a survey using Django and Ajax. I am have a bit of trouble on getting values updated in database. As shown here

[image: this screenshot of CMD]

my SQL values is always blank even though there's value printed (The RxCx is value it got from request.POST.get)

Models.py

```
class Office(models.Model):
    Office_Space = (
        ('R1B1', 'R1B1'),
        ('R2B1', 'R2B1'),
        ('R3B1', 'R3B1'),
        ('R1B2', 'R1B2'),
        ('R2B2', 'R2B2'),
        ('R3B2', 'R3B2'),
        ('R1B3', 'R1B3'),
        ('R2B3', 'R2B3'),
        ('R3B3', 'R3B3')
    )
    space = models.CharField(max_length=4, choices=Office_Space)
```

Forms.py

```
 from django import forms
 from Survey.models import Office 

 class officeForm(forms.ModelForm):
     class Meta:
         model = Office
         fields = ['space',]
```

Function in views (views is poorly written but if I do it other ways the form ends up being invalid...)

```
def get_Office(request):
    form_class = officeForm

    if request.method == 'POST':
        space = request.POST.get('result')  
        response_data = {}      
        print(space) # here is the RxCx printed for debugging
        response_data['space'] = space
        form = Office()
        form.save()
        print (connection.queries) #the SQL log          
        return JsonResponse(response_data)
    else:
        form = officeForm()
    return render(request, 'Front.html', {'officeform': form})
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If any of the below answers helped you to resolve your issue, please mark one as correct, please. It's a good practice in StackOverflow :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not passing the `form` any data (!), that's why it's empty. In order to work, pass to the `form` the `response_data` dict. Like this:

```
form = Office(response_data)
```

Correction: The above line will still not work because `Office` is the model, where you need the form which you have declared as `form_class`. So,

```
form = form_class(response_data)
```

or even better, remove the `form_class = officeForm` line and just write:

```
form = officeForm(response_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

view.py

```
def get_Office(request):
    form_class = officeForm(request.POST or None)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form_class.is_valid():
            space = request.POST.get('result')  
            response_data = {}      
            print(space) # here is the RxCx printed for debugging
            response_data['space'] = space
            form_class.save()
            print (connection.queries) #the SQL log          
            return JsonResponse(response_data)

    return render(request, 'Front.html', {'officeform': form_class})
```

Comment: Thank you! So I have tried with this function; however the form_class is not valid every time I click one radio button (since the rest is not filled). But I need some kind of update everytime the user clicks a radio button. How can I avoid the is_valid being false?